# Xcode 5: enable/disable entitlements file

Tags: xcode, xcode5, entitlements

How can I enable or disable entitlements file in my project? In previous version of Xcode(4.2), it was like in below image, but in Xcode 5 I couldn't find it.

In code hierarchy, entitlement file is present, as it was added with previous version of Xcode.

[image]

Comment: I would like to know also.

Answer (score 8):

- Go to the build settings of your target.
- Make sure that you have "All" selected instead of "Basic"
- Type "entitlements" into the search box
- The result is the build setting where you can specify where your entitlements file is located

It is worth noting that, for the most part in Xcode 5 you do not need the entitlements file as most of its responsibility is handled automatically by Xcode and in the provisioning profile of your app.